# Check if string contains another string

Tags: php, mysql

In php is there a way i can check if a string includes a value. 
Say i had a string "this & that", could i check if that included "this".
Thanks

UPDATED:

$u = username session

```
function myLeagues2($u)
{
     $q = "SELECT * FROM ".TBL_FIXTURES." WHERE `home_user` = '$u' GROUP BY `compname` ";
   return mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
```

}

That code returns if there is an exact match in the database. 
But i put two usernames together like "username1 & username2" and need to check if the username session is present in that field.

Is that a way to do this? It obviously woudn't equal it.

ANOTHER UPDATE:

If i use the like %username% in the sql, will it appear if its just the username. So rather than Luke & Matt being shown, if its just Luke will that show too? I dont want it to, i just want things that arent. Can you put != and LIKE so you only get similar matches but not identical?

Cheers

Comment: Now this is a completely different subject. MySQL has nothing to do with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like [`stristr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php) the best because it is case insensitive.

Usage example from php.net:

```
$email = 'USER@EXAMPLE.com';
echo stristr($email, 'e'); // outputs ER@EXAMPLE.com
echo stristr($email, 'e', true); // As of PHP 5.3.0, outputs US
```

#### based on your update

I think you want to use the `like` statement

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE home_user LIKE "%username1%" OR home_user LIKE "%username2%"
GROUP BY compname
```

The `%` Is your wild card.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`strstr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) or [`strpos`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) functions. Although there are regex ways too but not worth for such trivial task there.

**Using `strstr`**

```
if (strstr('This & That', 'This') !== false)
{
   // found
}
```

**Using `strpos`**

```
if (strpos('This & That', 'This') !== false)
{
   // found
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks, could you give a brief example how I could use this?

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. 
Can you check my updated original post, what i want to do is slightly different, dont know if there is another way to do this.

Comment: @Luke: I don't understand your update, you should post more code about how you want to compare with as you say `"username1 & username2"`. It is not clear to me, you should post more code or explain a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php>
$string = 'this & that';
if (strpos($string, 'this') === FALSE) {
    echo 'this does not exist!';
} else {
    echo 'this exists!';
}
?>
```

What's noteworthy in the check is using a triple equal (forget the actual name).  strpos is going to return 0 since it's in the 0th position.  If it was only '== FALSE' it would see the 0 and interpret it as FALSE and would show 'this does not exist'.  Aside from that this is about the most efficient way to check if something exists.

Answer (score -2):

```
preg_match('/this/','this & that');
```

This returns the number of matches, so if it's 0, there were no matches. It will however stop after 1 match.

Comment: Yeah, good point. I just threw it out as a second option because we don't know what the OP's ultimate goal is.

Answer (score -2):

Regular expressions can be checked with [preg-match.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)